# setOnClickListener never fired - Android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, events, button

I'm having a problem that seems to be quite common but none of the solutions on here so far have helped me.

I am trying to add a simple button to my app which will start a new activity when clicked.

The button displays ok in my app but when I touch it nothing happens.

My problem is that setOnClickListener() is never fired - when I debug it just skips right over it and no logging message is displayed in LogCat.

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sarah.tourapplication.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/belowlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cam_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Take Picture" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener  {

Button camButton;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent locationUpdatesIntent = new Intent(this, GetLocationUpdates.class);
        startActivity(locationUpdatesIntent);

        camButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cam_button);

        //add button functionality 

        camButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Button was clicked.");
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(cameraIntent);
            }
        });



    }
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? I'd really appreciate any pointers.

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 8 and everything I'm using is up to date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why call startActivity in onCreate of MainActivity?

Comment: Because I want to start an activity when the main activity is created. Is this incorrect?

Comment: camButton works in MainActivity.`findViewById` find view in MainActivity,not GetLocationUpdates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. It turns out that I was calling the click handler in the wrong activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines

```
Intent locationUpdatesIntent = new Intent(this, GetLocationUpdates.class);
startActivity(locationUpdatesIntent);
```

It looks like you're starting a different activity before you actually get to the point where you're adding the listener...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm on my phone but try to use setOnClickListener(this); and override the onClick method. Inside the onClick method use if (view == yourview) to do w/e you want. :). If it still doesn't work try removing the startActivity method at the very beginning of your codes